# tqdm and termplotlib interfering in terminal/mixing stdout

Tags: python, tqdm

When I combine the two e.g.

```
 loop_obj= tqdm(enumerate(my_iter),total= N)

 for i, (stuff) in tqdm(enumerate(my_iter), total = N):

        loop_obj.set_description(f"Iter: {i}")
    ....
 fig = tpl.figure()
 counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins = my_bins)
 fig.hist(counts, bin_edges, orientation="horizontal")
 fig.show()
```

[image]